# How to get list item name in android with out onItemClick()

Tags: android

I am trying to implement contextmenu for list item ,here i want to collect list item name when we press and hold the list item,how to get it.In onItemclick() by using adapter we can get the position so that we can access list item name but for this means if we press and hold the list item how to get the name ??Help me,Thanks
Here is code

```
public class ListFileActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener,
    OnCompletionListener, OnItemClickListener {

public String path;
MediaPlayer mda;
int current_index2 = 0;
String filename;
Button backToRecord, allvoices, btnpause, btnplay;
ToggleButton activateDelete;
ListView myList;
List values;
ArrayAdapter adapter;
MediaPlayerActivity mp = new MediaPlayerActivity();
private SongsManager songManager;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
public int currentSongIndex = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.soundrecords);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    backToRecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonrecord);
    activateDelete = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonedit);
    allvoices = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoncontinuous);
    btnpause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonpause);
    btnplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonplay);

    myList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    backToRecord.setOnClickListener(this);
    activateDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
    allvoices.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnpause.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnplay.setOnClickListener(this);

    myList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    // Use the current directory as title
    path = "/sdcard/";
    if (getIntent().hasExtra("path")) {
        path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
    }
    setTitle(path);
    // Read all files sorted into the values-array
    values = new ArrayList();
    File dir = new File(path);
    if (!dir.canRead()) {
        setTitle(getTitle() + " (inaccessible)");
    }
    final String[] list = dir.list();
    if (list != null) {
        for (String file : list) {
            if (file.contains(".3gp")) {
                values.add(file);
            }
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(values);
    // Put the data into the list
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            android.R.id.text1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(myList);
}

final int CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE = 1;
final int CONTEXT_MENU_RENAME = 2;

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE, Menu.NONE, "silmek");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_RENAME, Menu.NONE, "adını değiştirmek");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();
    Long id = myList.getAdapter().getItemId(info.position);
    final int number_of_item_in_listview = Integer.valueOf(id.intValue());

    final int context_menu_number = item.getItemId();

    switch (item.getItemId()) { // retrieves the id of the item clicked. In
                                // this case it can 1,2 or 3 as we declared
                                // it earlier.
    case CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE:
        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Eğer madde kaldırıldı" + number_of_item_in_listview
                        + "listeden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            values.remove(number_of_item_in_listview);
        // myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //if this does not work,
        // reinitialize the adapter:
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                values);
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);
        File f = new File(path + filename);
        if (f != null && f.exists()) {
            // delete it
            f.delete();
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                    values);
            myList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        return (true);

    case CONTEXT_MENU_RENAME:

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("öğeyi yeniden adlandırmak");
        alert.setMessage("Seçili öğe için yeni bir isim girin");

        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);

        alert.setPositiveButton("tamam",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int whichButton) {
                        String value = input.getText().toString();
                        values.set(number_of_item_in_listview, value
                                + ".3gp");
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        /*
                         * File sdcard =
                         * Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); File
                         * from = new File(sdcard,"from.txt"); File to = new
                         * File(sdcard,"to.txt"); from.renameTo(to);
                         */
                        File f = new File(path + filename);
                        if (f != null && f.exists()) {
                            File from = new File(f, f.getName());
                            File to = new File(f, value);
                            from.renameTo(to);
                        }
                    }
                });

        alert.setNegativeButton("iptal",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int whichButton) {
                    }
                });
        alert.show();
        return (true);
    }
    return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

Comment: Then use Long Click listener for that

Comment: I know Long click but requirement is different ,i have several options in context menu in one option i need this list item name.

Comment: Posted,i think my explanation is good compared to posting code?

Answer (score 0):

AdapterView also has a method named, `setOnItemLongClickListener()`. On passing the object of `AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener`, a method which is implemented, namely, `onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)`. In this method you can get same working mechanism as you want.

You can get the name by using `position` argument of `onItemLongClick()` as:

(Assuming your data is stored in `ArrayList<String>`),

```
String selectedItem = arrayList.get(position);
```

Comment: I know Long click but requirement is different ,i have several options in context menu in one option i need this list item name

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();
    String name = value.get(info.position).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = myList.getAdapter().getItem(currentSongIndex).toString();
```

Here is solution